# Нужно ли тире перед таким фразеологизом

Tags: синтаксис

> А у меня сын () мухи не обидит.

Перед фразеологизмом "мухи не обидит" нужно тире? Согласно правилам вроде бы должно ставиться, но что-то препятствует мне ставить соответствующий знак.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ПРО МУХ
Бедная маленькая мушка запросто может потеряться в таком 
огромном городе, как Москва. Именно об этом размышлял 
Грзенк, меланхолично собирая хоботком капельки чая в 
подсобной комнате музея Лермонтова. 
Внезапно, почти оглушив его, на стол обрушилось что- 
то огромное и шумное. Газета! Грзенк взвился и перелетел на 
люстру... Обнаружив, что ему удалось спастись, женщина 
испытала всплеск глубочайшего разочарования. Как Грзенк ни 
старался, он не обнаружил в ее сознании ни тени сострадания. 
Видимо, совершить убийство ей ровным счетом ничего не 
стоило. Грзенку стало страшно. «Какая опасная и агрессивная 
планета!»
```

**ОТВЕТ**

Правильно:

*А у меня сын / **мУхи не обидит**. Добрый и совсем не агрессивный. Он не способен к плохим поступкам.*

Это **[устойчивое сочетание](https://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/1266/%D0%9C%D0%A3%D0%A5%D0%98_%D0%9D%D0%95_%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%98%D0%94%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%AC),**  которое в предложении является именной частью сказуемого, а не таким фразеологизмом, о котором говорится в правилах. Оборот речи естественно вписывается в предложение, поэтому **тире** обычно не ставится, паузы нет.

В общем случае выбор знака зависит **от контекста.** Тире ставится, если нужно логически подчеркнуть **первую часть предложения.**

*А у мЕня сын — // **мухи не обидит**.*

**[Примеры предложений](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82)**

Comment: «_**Вода, вода, кругом вода**_…»

Comment: Какая уж там вода! Пустыня!  Один орел кричит другому:   — Ты кого-нибудь ви-идишь?  —  Не-ет! — И я  нет!

Comment: Еще классика можно вспомнить https://www.culture.ru/poems/5338/glukhoi-glukhogo-zval-k-sudu Это я к тому, что в этой теме каждый говорит о своем. Кто о фразеологизме и правилах, кто об устойчивом сочетании и контексте, а кто об интонационном тире в общих чертах.  Только я ни одного тире в примерах из литературы  не вижу.

Comment: Там тоже фразеологизмы являются именной частью. В чем разница тогда?

Comment: В правилах? Там речевой оборот НЕ ВПИСЫВАЕТСЯ в структуру предложения. Сравнить: Талант у него — дай бог каждому.   Талант у него такой, что дай бог каждому.  И сравните с примерами из карты слов https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/мухи+не+обидит

Comment: @Sharon: «_В правилах? Там речевой оборот НЕ ВПИСЫВАЕТСЯ в структуру предложения. Сравнить_…» ===  А в этих примерах из разбираемого правила тоже не вписывается: _Избушка — так себе , амбар… А Виктор — ни в отца ни в мать_…» ❓

Comment: Ага, ни  в мать ни в отца, а в проезжего молодца. Так ведь надо. // Так себе нареч. качеств.-обстоят. разг, а совсем не фразеологизм  //А вообще я за каждый речевой оборот не отвечаю. Сами уж разбирайтесь.

Answer (score 0):

По основным правилам как раз не нужно. Но можно поставить интонационное тире.

[Интонационное тире](https://rozental.gramatik.ru/xxi-tire-mezhdu-chlenami-predlozheniya/ss-81-intonacionnoe-tire)

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, интонационное тире можно или нужно поставить?

Comment: Тире ставится при сказуемом, выраженном фразеологическим оборотом: Пирог — пальчики оближешь ; Талант у него — дай бог каждому ; Мать от радости прослезилась, а отец — хоть бы что!  (Крут.); Избушка — так себе , амбар (Шукш.); Сам Ефим — пальца в рот не клади  (Шукш.); А Виктор — ни в отца ни в мать  (Крут.); Ночь — хоть глаз выколи!  (А. Цвет.).

Наличие частицы не, а также вводных слов при устойчивых сочетаниях в роли сказуемого препятствует постановке тире (но не запрещает): Офицер этот не чета вам , господин жандарм (Фед.);

Comment: Список литературы
Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина //3. Тире между членами предложения, §14

Comment: @Sharon, интонационное тире ставится  по условием контекста. И об этом я пишу. Можно поставить.

Comment: Это да, но обратите внимание на вопрос "Нужно ли тире перед таким фразеологизмом".  Для данной темы есть особые правила, и автор приводит эти правила в комментариях.  Эта тема у вас не раскрыта: как интонационное тире соотносится с этим правилом.

Comment: – 
@Sharon, я писал наспех и не раскрыл тему. Но вы уже все написали. Поддерживаю ваш ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш голос.